# GUI login works, CLI login fails

Tags: upgrade, login

If I try to login to a GUI via lightdm or sddm, no problem. If I try to login to a virtual terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>...) it lets you type a username and press enter but it then acts like something has been entered into password and cursor goes to the next line and says invalid login 4 times in a row before "resetting" to the top of the screen as if no login attempt has occurred.

Basically, if I had to guess, I think the upgrade must have broken something with .bashrc or related files. I do not know where to look to diagnose the issue.

This issue is immediately following an upgrade from ubuntu 16.04.whatever the latest was to 18.04.2
Things may have been interrupted during the upgrade, I'm not sure. (I did it overnight and slept while it upgraded and it had rebooted when I came back)
I reran do-release-upgrade to make sure and it asks if I want to go to 18.10 and nothing else seems wrong. Give me a hand please?

Comment: I confirm the issue is no longer present after kernel version change.